# Eigenvalues of hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am just a bit confused, so:

Is determining eigenvalues of hermitian matrix basically the same as how we determine eigenvalues of real-number matrices?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Find Characteristic equation and solve.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of a hermitian matrix has all coefficients real. You can write a companion matrix from these coefficients. The companion matrix is a real matrix.